# How to get the width of a matplotlib text, including the padded bounding box?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know how to get the width of the text:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import BoxStyle

xpos, ypos = 0, 0
text = 'blah blah'

boxstyle = BoxStyle("Round", pad=1)
props = {'boxstyle': boxstyle,
         'facecolor': 'white',
         'linestyle': 'solid',
         'linewidth': 1,
         'edgecolor': 'black'}

textbox = plt.text(xpos, ypos, text, bbox=props)
plt.show()
textbox.get_bbox_patch().get_width() # 54.121092459652573
```

However, this does not take into account the padding. Indeed, if I set the padding to 0, I get the same width.

```
boxstyle = BoxStyle("Round", pad=0)
props = {'boxstyle': boxstyle,
         'facecolor': 'white',
         'linestyle': 'solid',
         'linewidth': 1,
         'edgecolor': 'black'}

textbox = plt.text(xpos, ypos, text, bbox=props)
plt.show()
textbox.get_bbox_patch().get_width() # 54.121092459652573
```

My question is: how can I get the width of the surrounding box? or how can I get the size of the padding in the case of a FancyBoxPatch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [`matplotlib.patches.FancyBboxPatch`](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.FancyBboxPatch) class is similar to [`matplotlib.patches.Rectangle`](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle) class, but it draws
>   a fancy box around the rectangle.
>
> [`FancyBboxPatch.get_width()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.FancyBboxPatch.get_width) returns the width of the (inner) rectangle

However, [`FancyBboxPatch`](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.FancyBboxPatch) is a subclass of [`matplotlib.patches.Patch`](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch) which provides a [`get_extents()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.get_extents) method:

> [`matplotlib.patches.Patch.get_extents()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.get_extents)
>
> Return a Bbox object defining the axis-aligned extents of the Patch.

Thus, what you need is **`textbox.get_bbox_patch().get_extents().width`**.

Comment: Thanks very much :-) I spent a long time looking for this.